# Unable to intercept backbutton on Cordova Crosswalk

Tags: android, cordova

I am working with Crosswalk Cordova & jQuery Mobile, and it seems I cannot intercept the backbutton.

Here are some observations :

- I can intercept the menu button
- Pressing the backbutton sends me to the previous jQuery Mobile page, but I cannot change this behaviour
- I can intercept the backbutton with the same code in "normal" Cordova

I am using crosswalk-cordova-8.37.189.12-arm, and here is the code :

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",    onDeviceReady, false); 
});

function onDeviceReady()
{ 
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", backbutton_action,  false);
}

function backbutton_action() 
{
   ...
}
```

Am I doing something wrong ? I would be glad to hear your thoughts about this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for trying Crosswalk Cordova. It's work normally in my testing with crosswalk-cordova-8.37.189.12-arm. please check the App plugin need install in res/xml/config.xml file.

```
<feature name="App">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
</feature>
```

please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. These lines are present in the res/xml/config.xml, but it is not working anyway

Comment: Sorry for this false alarm. I updated to crosswalk-cordova-8.37.189.14-arm and it is now working perfectly.